# How do I send cookie on my requests with nextauth on nextjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, next-auth

I am using Nextjs for the first time. Previously, I had authentication system where when a user logs in, the user gets access token and refresh token. The refresh token is in a cookie like this:

```
  const logUserInfo = {
            id: user?.id ,
            role: user?.role,
            username: user?.username,
            profilepicture: user?.profilepicture,
            email: user?.email
        } as jwtUserAttributes;

        //generate access token
        const userToken =  userJWT(logUserInfo);

        //generate session token
        const userRefreshToken = JWTRefresh(user?.id);

        res.cookie('refreshJWT', userRefreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 604800000,
        } )

        
        return res.status(200).json({userToken: userToken});
```

I could access the refresh token this way:

```
  const cookies = req.cookies;
```

I used the cookies to handle refresh token logics since it was stored there.

When I switched to using nextAuth on the clientside and I cant seem to access the cookies anymore when the user logs in when I check `const cookies = req.cookies;`

Here is my nextauth code:

```
   const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req, res) => {

   return{
     session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
     },
     providers:[
      CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
       credentials: {},

          async authorize(credentials, req){
          const { username, password } = credentials as {
              username: string;
              password: string;
            };

            if(!credentials){
              return null
            }
            const userData = {
              username: username,
              password: password
            }
          

            try {
              
              const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, userData);
              if(response?.data){
                
                const user: jwtDecodedAttributes = jwt_decode(response?.data?.userToken);
                console.log(user, userData, 'hey');
                const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie']

                res.setHeader('set-Cookie', cookies as string[])
            
                return {
                  id: user.userId,
                  name: user.username,
                  role: user.role,
                  profilepicture: user.profilepicture,
                  iat: user?.iat,
                  exp: user?.exp,
                  username: user?.username,
                  token: response?.data?.userToken,
                  email: user.email,
                  userId: user?.userId
                };
          }
           
              
            } catch (error) {
              
              
            }
            return null
      }
   } )
   ],

pages: {
  signIn: "/login",  
},

  callbacks:{
   async jwt({token, user}){

    return {...token, ...user} ;
  },

  async session({session, token, user}){
  
  session.user = token
 
  
  return session
 }
}
}
};

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
 return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
}
```

If I login from postman, I get to see the cookies via `req.cookies`. If I login via nextauth, I wont see it.
So, what I have decided to do is to get the cookie from nextAuth response, store it in localstorage and retrieve it when the route that needs it would be called. Is this okay?